# Make Chrome frame installer not ask user for admin privileges?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

I have an HTML5 site with canvas etc that uses Chrome frame to work on IE8 and older browsers.

The installer currently (as of Oct 11 2011) asks the user for Admin privileges to 'make changes to this computer'.

However in testing it seems that even if the user clicks 'no', that Chrome frame still installs (I can see it rendering canvas elements etc).

I'd like not to bother users with the password prompt, as it seems unnecessary (and a bit scary).

Is there a way I can have users install Chrome Frame without prompting users for their password?

Comment: This question was answered in the Google Chrome Frame group here: https://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/280cedd160979810. The answer is yes, simply point your users to: http://www.google.com/chromeframe?user=true

Comment: @Kevin do you want to add an answer below so I can mark the question as complete?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's the URL Robert Shield provided, attached to the CFinstall.check():

```
CFInstall.check({
   mode: "overlay",
   url: "http://www.google.com/chromeframe?user=true",
   destination: "http://yoursite.com"
});
```

This will install Chrome Frame on a per-user basis by default.